# How to make a visual table comparison?

Tags: tables, info-visualisation, data-tables

I have to redesign a comparison between the two tables. The rows with differences should highlight the attribute which is different (see image). My problem is: it grows really fast. I start thinking about presenting a pixel heat map with interactions to "zoom in" in a "details on-demand" fashion. But I am not sure about that because it could be a too drastic difference for users.

[image]

Comment: Are the tables populated from a DB as Flex, Grid, or HTML tables? What language is being used -- PHP?

Comment: Hey @Steve, thanks for your time. It is a web application, so I would answer HTML.

Comment: Above the table it says, "1 to 5 of 37 entries" so that indicates a database output. Are you asking for how to code this? Because it is already being shown in your screenshot. If you are not asking for code, what are you asking for? Your screenshot answers the question at the top of the page, so it's hard to answer it. That may be why there are no answers.

Comment: Hi Steve. No, I am not asking about how to code. I am asking about design hints. I have to facilitate this task of "Table comparison" in a row by row fashion. The current design (the one in the picture) scales really bad and it is by nature a 2 lines row/result in a Listview (which is also bad). I hope that now I made my question clearer. 

Let me know in case of further doubts and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of the reasons for having to create this table is to help with cleaning up the dataset. And since you mentioned that the rows grow really fast, that means there must be any number of columns that might be mismatched. If it is usually just the type of mismatch shown on the screen shot, I don't think it would be much of an issue because that's probably exactly what you want to see.

So if we take the case that any number of columns might be mismatched, what you probably need are additional filters that let you narrow down the amount of rows that you are looking at. This could be a simple filter on a single column type, or something more complex with multiple filters based on specific criteria.

This will limit the amount of changes that you have to make to the design.